# Can i debug nodejs web application like .net

Tags: .net, node.js, debugging, sails.js

I am programmer of .net and currently working in node js using sails ,
now I'd like to know if i can debug sails project just like in .net (line by line) is there any way to achieve this functionality?

Please let me know if there is any way.

**Note:** I am using sublime text editor.

Answer (score 1):

For debugging .net you use Visual Studio. For debugging nodejs i recomend you use WebStorm IDE http://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/

For sublime you can use Web Inspector http://sokolovstas.github.io/SublimeWebInspector/

But I prefer use console.log to detect the problem, it is more faster way that launch debugger.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Node Inspector](https://github.com/node-inspector/node-inspector) to turn your browser into a line-by-line debugger for node apps, complete with breakpoints and interactive console.

First, install [Node Inspector](https://github.com/node-inspector/node-inspector):

```
npm install -g node-inspector
```

Then start your sails app in debug mode.  You can do `node --debug app.js` instead of `sails lift`, or in Sails v0.10.x, do `sails debug`.

Finally, start the node inspector with

```
node-inspector
```

On *nix systems, you can run it in the background with `node-inspector &`.

Then you can go to open `http://127.0.0.1:8080/debug?port=5858` to debug your app.  Works best in the Chrome browser.